# A radar/spider plot with a median (black line) and interquartile range (gray shaded area)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, radar-chart

I want to create a radar/spider plot with a median (black line) and interquartile range (gray shaded area) like this

[image]

But I created this plot

[image]

My guess is, I have to calculated the distance between Quantil1 and Quantil3 but I don't know how to plot this.

My dataset with my code

```
(df.m)
Max                  7.000000        7.000000
Min                  1.000000        1.000000
Quartile1            4.000000        4.000000
Quartile3            6.333333        6.000000
Average              5.113889        4.490099

radarchart(
  df.m, axistype = 1, seg = 6, cglty = 1,axislabcol = "black", cglcol = "black", 
  pfcol = c(alpha("#99999980",0.4),"#99999980",NA), caxislabels = c(1:7),vlcex = 0.5,calcex = 0.8,
  pcol= c(NA,NA, 2), plty = 1, plwd = 2, vlabels =  c("1", "2" ,"3", "4", "5"),
)
```

```
radarchart(
  df.m, axistype = 1, seg = 6, cglty = 1,axislabcol = "black", cglcol = "black", 
  pfcol = c(alpha("#99999980",0.4),"#99999980",NA), caxislabels = c(1:7),vlcex = 0.5,calcex = 0.8,
  pcol= c(NA,NA, 2), plty = 1, plwd = 2, vlabels =  c("1", "2" ,"3", "4", "5"),
)
```

I'm thinking about using ggplot2 but I dont know where to start.